# How do I write a recursive function that multiplies each character in a string by 2?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm trying to complete a recursive function which given a number, returns a string where the returned value has duplicate of each digit

Example: if 507, returns 550077

if the number is only 0 then just return 0

also if it is a negative number, return the negative sign only once

Example: -507 returns -550077

I haven't yet implemented anything to recognize a negative number, I was just trying to get my function to work first

so far I have:

```
def double(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    else:
        x = str(x)
        return x[0]*2 + double(x[1: ])

print(double(527))
```

however this returns IndexError: string index out of range
I had it working by printing the result instead of returning the result, but the problem I am trying to solve strictly wants the result returned, not printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably intend `len(x) == 0` instead of `x == 0`

Comment: You're having trouble because sometimes `x` is a number, sometimes it's a string. If it's a string, when should the recursion stop? That's the case you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works recursively, fixes the x==0 termination error, checks whether a character is a digit before doubling, and returns the final answer as an int (instead of a str).

```
def double(x):
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        first_char = x[0]

        # only double if it's an integer
        if first_char in map(str, range(10)):
            first_char *= 2
        return int(first_char + str(double(x[1: ])))

print(double(-527))

>>> -552277
```

Comment: thanks! instead of using map though I did 
    elif x[0] == "-":
        return "-" + x[1]*2 + double(x[2: ])
only because of the fact its a question I'm studying for an exam and I don't think the professor wants the map function used.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
def double(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    else:
        x = str(x)
        l=[]
        for a in x:
            if a == '-':
                l.append(a)
            else:
                l.append(a*2)
        return ''.join(l)
```

Comment: OP wanted recursive solution.